# Modifying an ImageView's color and opacity from a PictureDrawable

Tags: java, android, imageview, android-drawable

I'm using [this library](https://github.com/Pixplicity/sharp) for SVG image rendering. The library itself is unable to change the Picture opacity and color. There is [an issue tracking this](https://github.com/Pixplicity/sharp/issues/28), but I'd like to work around this in my code.

I'm getting SVG image data my API and storing the files in a local directory. I then load the SVG into an ImageView as follows:

```
Sharp.loadFile(new File(StickerList.get(position).get_thumbnail_url()))
    .into(holder.nuggetImageView);
```

This approach using `loadFile().into()` loads my SVG image into an ImageView, as expected. However, I'm not successful in changing the image color and opacity change. I've tried doing this as follows:

```
ImageView imageView = imageRootView.findViewById(R.id.photo_editor_sdk_image_iv);

imageView.setColorFilter(colorFilter);
imageView.setAlpha(alpha);
```

This appears to have no effect at all. What would be a way of changing the color and opacity?